# Public/private key setup in server

Tags: unix

I am using CentOS 7 in my personal laptop. I have created Public/Private keys ( SSH key pair) for that user. I can see the two keys also in the path /home/user/.ssh/. After creating the key pairs I have coped the public key to the  file  " .ssh/authorized_keys " and disabled the root access for the user in the file " .ssh/sshd_config" after that I restarted the ssh services. So I wanted to know how I can restrict others accessing my server based on keys ( even if he has password he should not be able to login without key). I am not sure how to use those keys which I created.

Answer (score 1):

Once your are sure that you can login with your keypair, you can add this line to your sshd config on the server :

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and restart your sshd service

It will prevent any password authentication. You will only connect using your private key.

Comment: I did but after that when I connect to server using putty it is throwing error as "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"  but I want to know how I will enable the public/private keys to login